# Unable to access properties of object stored in a React state

Tags: reactjs, object

I am using React hooks and I need to store the data from my server which is an object, to a state.

**This is my state:**

```
  const [sendingTime,setSendingTime] = useState({})
```

**This is how I set it inside useEffect:**

```
    const getTime= () =>{
        axios.get("https://localhost:1999/api/getLastUpdatedTime")
            .then(res => {

                console.log(res.data)

                setSendingTime({sendingTime : res.data})
          
                console.log('sendingTime is coimng',sendingTime)

            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }


 useEffect(() => {
        getCount()
        getTime()
    },[])
```

Now when I console.log the object state it returns an empty object. Although if I set the object to any variable and then console.log it it doesn't return an empty object. But both ways I am unable to access the properties of the object.

### Edit

This is what I was doing previously:

```
 const[time,setTime] = useState({
        totalComplaintsTime: '00:00',
        resolvedComplaintsTime: '00:00',
        unresolvedComplaintsTime:'00:00',
        assignedComplaintsTime:'00:00',
        supervisorsTime:'00:00',
        rejectedComplaintsTime:'00:00'

    })

  const getTime= () =>{
        axios.get("https://localhost:1999/api/getLastUpdatedTime")
            .then(res => {

                console.log(res.data)

                setTime({
                    totalComplaintsTime: res.data.Complaints[0].updatedAt,
                    resolvedComplaintsTime:  res.data.Resolved[0].updatedAt,
                    unresolvedComplaintsTime: res.data.Unresolved[0].updatedAt ,
                    assignedComplaintsTime: res.data.Assigned[0].updatedAt ,
                    rejectedComplaintsTime: res.data.Rejected[0].updatedAt,
                    supervisorsTime: res.data.Supervisors[0].updatedAt
                })

            

            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }

 useEffect(() => {

        getCount()

        // getTime()

        getTime()
    },[])
```

And this is how I used the states to set the dynamic values :

```
Last updated at {time.resolvedComplaintsTime}
```

This is working perfectly fine but I wanted to store the data in an object state and then access it, which would've been easier and  more efficient. Also I wanted to pass this object to another component. That is why I wanted to make a state and store the data in that state.

### Solved

So the main problem was accessing the data throughout the component. This is the solution:

sendingTime is being initialized but only when a render occurs. So we add a piece of code to check if that state is initialized or not.

This is where I wanted to display the data.

```
 <div key={sendingTime.length}  className={classes.stats}>
            <UpdateIcon fontSize={"small"} /> Last updated at{" "}
              {Object.keys(sendingTime).length > 0 &&
              sendingTime.Complaints[0].updatedAt}
          </div>
```

This way I can access the properties of the object stored in the sendingTime state very easily.

Comment: You prob don't want the length as a key for the item. Also, you don't need to wrap `fontSize="small"` in brackets.

Comment: what else can i give as the key?

Comment: Well, it's hard to say given the partial snipped, but you would probably want a unique key for the item like a database ID  or unique name.

Answer (score 1):

`setSendingTime` comes from a `useState` so it is asynchronous:

When you call:

```
setSendingTime({sendingTime : res.data})
console.log('sendingTime is coimng',sendingTime)
```

The state `sendTime` has not been updated, so it display the init value which is {}

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, [setState is asynchronous](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3) so you will only be able to get `sendingTime`'s new value on the next re-render. And as @Enchew mentions, you probably don't want to set an object as that value most likely.

Try this instead:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(undefined)

const getTime = () => {
  axios.get("https://localhost:1999/api/getLastUpdatedTime")
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(data)
      setData(data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
}

useEffect(() => {
  getCount()
  getTime()
}, [])

if (!data) return <p>No data...</p>

return (
  <>
    <p>Complaints: {data.Complaints[0].updatedAt}<p>
    <p>Resolved: {data.Resolved[0].updatedAt}<p>
    <p>{/* ...etc... */}</p>
  </>
)
```

You should see the value you're expecting to see in the console.log because you're using the locally scoped variable, not the asynchronous value, which will only be updated on the next re-render.

Comment: Ok yes, I do see the data now, but I am logging 'data' right now. If I am log sendingTime it still shows an empty object. Since it's empty I still can't access its properties throughout the component.

Comment: Because it is async and won't be set till next re-render (as I mentioned). This is a known property of setting state with a hook in React

Comment: How can I fix it then? I also tried to store the data in a variable object, that maybe it will work that way, I could see the variable in console.log but then again there was still the problem of accessing its properties. It gave me this error = TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: You need to provide more context/examples, because what you have doesn't show me what you're trying to do. You must access to `sendingTime` value in your component and it will match the value you set from `setSendingTime` on the *next* re-render (not the current one)

Comment: Okay so I have one useEffect in there I am calling a function getTime. In that function I fetch the data which is an object =  {Complaints: Array(1), Resolved: Array(1), Assigned: Array(1), Rejected: Array(1), Unresolved: Array(1), …}. And I set the sendingTime with the res.data this way setSendingTime(res.data) . I want to use this state to display the data in the return function of the component this way = Last updated at {sendingTime.Complaints[0].updatedAt} . But it gives me this error =  TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Check the code above and see if it works,  I updated answer

Comment: But the problem is I want more than one updated times. This one is just for Complaints. I want the updated time from Assigned , rejected etc. And all of these are stored in the object(res.data) I'm receiving from the server.

Comment: You can take a look at my previous code, I had to make so many states and then set them with the data, and use each one of them separately to display the data. To reduce or improve the coding I wanted to store the data in the state object and then directly access the properties with that one state. Hence less number of states.

Comment: Why don't you just store the full response from the data then and access it in your component? You may have to have some checks to make sure the values are set first though.

Comment: @Aldor try my updated code and let me know if it is closer to what you need

Comment: Thanks @Dana Woodman. I've updated the question by adding the checks. It works perfectly fine now.

Comment: @Aldor glad you figured it out. If you think my answer solved it, please accept it/give it an upvote. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`setSendingTime` works asynchronously and your object may have not been saved in the state yet. Also pay attention to the way you save the time in your state, you are wrapping the result of the data in another object with property `sendingTime`, which will result in the following object: `sendingTime = { sendingTime: {/*data here */} }`. If you are running for `sendingTime: {/*data here */}` try the following:

```
const getTime = () => {
  axios
    .get('https://localhost:1999/api/getLastUpdatedTime')
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);

      setSendingTime(res.data);

      console.log('sendingTime is coimng', sendingTime);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
};
```

Also have a look at this - how to use hooks with a callback: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usestate-callback

Comment: ok I changed it to sendingTime(res.data) and I also added sendingTime to the useEffect deps like this : useEffect( () => { getCount()  getTime() } , [sendingTime]). It does console.log the object now but it keeps on rerendering. It never stops.

Comment: What kind of data is returned from the axios call? If it is an object and this object is defined by a unique property (for example id), use that property in the array of the second argument.

Comment: Also, how many times do you want to call useEffect()? If you want to call it ONLY ONCE after the component is initially rendered, use an empty array. Currently, when you pass the object you are making an infinite loop. I'll explain - you call getTime and change the data of time. After that, you tell React, that your data has changed (this is done when passing the time parameter in the array) and it calls useEffect again. Since  your data is an object, React is comparing its reference (which after every axios call is different).

Comment: This is being returned from res.data = {Complaints: Array(1), Resolved: Array(1), Assigned: Array(1), Rejected: Array(1), Unresolved: Array(1), …}. I want to call it once and I did had an empty array in the useEffect but due to that my state wasn't being intialized at all. It was empty

Comment: This is how I want to access its properties and display the data throughout the component : Last updated at {sendingTime.Complaints[0].updatedAt} . But sendtingTime isn't being initialized at all, also, it gives me this error = TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Comment: Even if I dont use react hooks and just store the object in a variable, I'm still not able to access its properties.